# Javascript get complete word after matching special character in string

Tags: javascript, string-matching

This code not running when put Textx-yz but runs fine when put Textx-y

I want a alert(Textx-yz) when put Textx-,Textx,Textx-yz in match

```
alert('Textabc Textx-yz TextTypeTestingText'.match(/Textx-yz\S+/)[0])
```

Comment: What is the logic behind what you need to match?

Comment: This regex `/Textx-yz\S+/` --> what does one expect it to achieve when used with `.match()`?

Comment: because when you use the pattern /Textx-y\S+/  on the string 'Textabc Textx-yz...' \S+' matches the z letter and fulfills it. While if you use the pattern `/Textx-yz\S+/` the regex finds the space that doesn't fulfill it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to find the complete word no matter what i put in match weather complete or partial text so if i put Textx-y it matches and give me my complete word but if i put Textx-yz it doesn't give me my word

Comment: @DiegoDeVita If i use .match(/Textx-\w*/) it works fine i get my complete word but if i use .match(/Textx\w*/) it does not take special character . so can you help with 
`If i put Textx result i want Textx-yz ............
If i put Textx- result i want Textx-yz ...........
If i put Textx-yz result i want Textx-yz`

Comment: You still don't get how regex works. `\w` is a class of character including (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ ) so the dash won't fulfill your expression if there's any in the string when \w was expected by the pattern. You should really read the basics about regex .. it will get not longer than 10 minutes to understand those very simple rules to begin with.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita If you get my requirements can you write some code and let me achive this

Comment: @RohitArora I wrote an answer trying to address any case in the way I tried to understand the requirements for your regular expression. Consider that some fine tuning requires considerations made on the result got from match.

Answer (score 0):

you can use word boundaries and exact match to get this match:

```
\b(Textx\-yz)+\b
```

[`\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) - searches whole words only

and in between we tell it what we want to find

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean you can this pattern:

```
'Textabc Textx-yz TextTypeTestingText'.match(/Textx-yz \S+/)[0]
```

Actually I add a space after `-yz`  in match method

Comment: It is working but it gives me next word also :) so may be this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you need the expression to match in any given string the pattern `Textx` followed or not by a dash and `[a-ZA-Z0-9_]` characters, the regex you are looking for is: `(Textx(-[\w]+)?)`

It's not perfectly clear what did you expect when the string contained an invalid expression like 'Textx- unwanted'. In this case my code returns 'Textx' with no following dash. Anyway I separated the capture group for the second part so that you could add further logic in the doMatch function doing some further consideration beyond the regex.

Here's a demo:

```js
function doMatch(subject){

  //this is an expression having 1 optional grouped capture as being the part "dash following something"
  let pattern = /Textx(-[\w]+)?/;  
  
  let match = subject.match(pattern);

  //the whole text matched by the expression
  //console.log(match[0]);
  //the optional text matched after Textx starting with dash and at least one \w char
  //this will be undefined if 'Textx-' or 'Textx' but not for 'Textx-anything'
  //console.log(match[1]); 
                               
  return match[0];
}

console.log('------begin------');

let matchedString;

//1- Textx (alone)
matchedString = doMatch('Textx');
console.log( matchedString ); //-> Textx

//2- Textx (alone and having further text later separated by space)
matchedString = doMatch('Textabc Textx unwanted');
console.log( matchedString ); //-> Textx

//3- Textx (followed by '-randomstuff')
matchedString = doMatch('Textabc Textx-randomstuff');
console.log( matchedString ); //-> Textx-randomstuff

//4- Textx (followed by '-randomstuff' and having further text later separated by space)
matchedString = doMatch('Textabc Textx-randomstuff unwanted');
console.log( matchedString ); //-> Textx-randomstuff

//5- Textx- (where the dash is not followed by valid characters and it's the end of string)
matchedString = doMatch('Textx-');
console.log( matchedString ); //-> Textx

//6- Textx- (where the dash is not followed by valid characters and there's further text)
matchedString = doMatch('Textabc Textx- unwanted');
console.log( matchedString ); //-> Textx
```